# Отправка и получение данных через в\из MySQL + PHP на Android

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

возникла необходимость производить отправку различных данных в базу данных MySQL из приложения Android, решил использовать связку MySQL + PHP для взаимодействия, походил по интернетам, почитал информацию был найден и скоректирован некоторый класс для данного действия, однако должным для меня образом он не работает.

Мне необходимо отправить через некоторый AsyncTask отправить данные на PHP скрипт, в запросе есть 2 переменных, это ID по которому необходимо найти нужный мне row и значение одной из переменных в нужном мне row.

Сам класс выглядит так:

```
private class DownloadsAPISet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String res;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AnimeActivity.this, "Система", "Пожалуйста подождите...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        res = null;
        PutUtility put = new PutUtility();

        put.setParam("mod_id", params[0].toString());
        put.setParam("actreaders", params[1].toString());

        try {
            res = put.postData("https://test.com/tool.php");
            Log.v("res", res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
        // Выполним тут получение чуть позже

    }
}
```

Сам PHP выглядит так:

```
<?php 

include('mysql.php');

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$return_arr = array();

$ModificationID=($_POST['mod_id']);
$ActiveReaders=($_POST['actreaders']);

$sql_download_update = "INSERT INTO 'repos'('actreaders') values (NULL,'".$ActiveReaders."')"; 
    $result_rower = $conn->query($sql_download_update);
        $row_array['errorcode1'] = 1; 

?>
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как мне в PHP выбрать именно нужный мне row и обновить его значение, а потом уже с Android обновить эти данные.

Прошу произвести разъяснение, заранее всем благодарем (( касательно возможной глупости вопроса: изучением Java и Android занимаюсь только 3-ий месяц, а PHP никогда до этого не использовал ))
Заранее всех благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш скрипт может только производить вставку данных в БД.
За это отвечает запрос `INSERT`, за изменение данных в БД будет отвечать запрос `UPDATE` с условием выборки `WHERE id = {$_GET|$_POST}`, где `{$_GET|$_POST}` - это параметр определяющий конкретную строку в БД.

Предполагаю что Вам следует проверить сперва существование строки и после выполнять нужный запрос.

Скрипт одержит вид:

```
<?php 

include('mysql.php');

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
        
$return_arr = array();
        
$ModificationID=($_POST['mod_id']);
$ActiveReaders=($_POST['actreaders']);
    
$check_sql = "SELECT Count(id) FROM repos WHERE id = ".$ModificationID;
$check = $conn->query($check_sql);

if(!$check)  $sql_download_update = "INSERT INTO repos values (NULL,'".$ActiveReaders."')"; 
else $sql_download_update = "UPDATE repos SET actreaders=".$ActiveReaders." WHERE id=".$ModificationID;

$result_rower = $conn->query($sql_download_update);
$row_array['errorcode1'] = 1; 

?>
```

Comment: Николай, строка точно существует и в бд изначально ( по умолчанию ) определена как 0, я хочу, чтобы когда я отправлял данные, по id выбирался нужный row и значение с 0 менялось на мою переменную. Причём,точно известно, что id не может неверным, а поле actreaders есть и равно 0.
Сейчас попробую сделать корректировку своего скрипта.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать отредактированный код

Comment: Это было именно то,что мне нужно, спасибо огромное. 
Пожалуй мне стоит подробнее ознакомиться с документацией по SQL , благодарю за помощь.